# What functions does the CLI perform before executing the command

Tags: methods, command-line-interface

So, this topic came up during a discussion about CLI and GUI and interfaces and all. And I gathered some information about it but could not find a definite complete answer.

So, think that you are developing a CLI for a set of API. So what functions can the CLI perform before it calls the particular method for the command that was entered.

There are few points that I was able to think of and also got from the internet.

- Validation of the command
- Security check

What else does a CLI do before executing the command?

Comment: This is a matter of opinion, but personally I would make the CLI do as little as you can.  Only just enough to permit it to actually make a request to the API.  (This might include some very basic validation or escaping of parameters.) This ensures you aren't locked into old behaviors in old versions of the deployed CLI when you've updated your API.

Comment: Even the security check should be delegated to the API under the APIs normal security model - obviously the CLI needs to know how to interract with the APIs security model, and may be able to prevalidate some aspects of the configured security, but it should not actually check that the operation is permitted - that should be up to the API.

Comment: @ChrisSimon, I think I was a little vague. What I wanted to know is, what does a CLI usually does before calling the API? The scenario example was to only show the big picture